# Read Lines in Text File then See if XML Files Contain Those Words Appeared in Text File

Tags: c#, winforms

Please bear with me as I am very new to programming itself and C# winforms.

I have an `AAA.txt` file where I make it appears in a combobox as "AAA". My main intention is to allow user to choose AAA from the dropdown combo, then click search. On the click event, the function should read the text file's content line by line and then find if these words (eg hello) or phrases (eg good morning) appear in all my 20 XML files' `<description></description>` child nodes. If these words/phrases do appear in certain `<description></description>` child nodes, then the data of whole `<item></item>` parent nodes will appear as results.

AAA.txt:

```
hello
good morning
great
bye
```

My function:

```
private void searchComByKeywords()
{ 
    string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir);
    foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        string docPath = fileName;
        xmlDoc.Load(docPath);
        XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("item");

        foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
        {
            XmlElement itemElement = (XmlElement)node;
            string itemDescription = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("description")[0].InnerText;

            if (itemDescription.ToLower().Contains(comboTemplates.SelectedItem.ToString()))
            {
                string itemTitle = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("title")[0].InnerText;
                string itemDate = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("pubDate")[0].InnerText;
                string itemAuthor = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("author")[0].InnerText;

                richComByTemplate.AppendText("Author: " + itemAuthor + "\nDate: " + itemDate + "\nTitle: " + itemTitle + "\nDescription: " + itemDescription + "\n\n--------\n\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I understand some may tell me to use LINQ-to-XML, but this is not my concern at this point. I know this line `if (itemDescription.ToLower().Contains(comboTemplates.SelectedItem.ToString()))` doesn't do what I want (it will search the word "AAA" instead of looking into the selected AAA text file). May I know how can I write this line correctly in order to read the words/phrases appear in the selected text file?

Thank you.

Comment: You know the problem - replace the data passed to .Contains(). Where does the data you want to search for come from?  (i.e. 'Hello'). Hard-coded? Other file? Other control?

Comment: the word "Hello" or phrase "Good morning" will come from a text file. I don't know how to read these words/phrases in the specific text file line by line then search if these words appear in XML files? I couldn't figure out what shall I put in the "if" statement. I was stuck there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The static `System.IO.File` class has a method `ReadAllLines` that reads all the lines of a text file into an array.

```
string[] words = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);
```

If the combo contains only the filename, you might want to supplement it with the directory name first

```
string dir = @"C:\MyDataPath";
string filename = comboTemplates.SelectedItem.ToString();
string filepath = Path.Combine(dir, filename);
```

Then put the words into a `HashSet<string>`

```
var wordSet = new HashSet<string>(words);
```

Then split your description into single words using a regular expression

```
var descrWords = 
    new HashSet<string>(
        Regex.Matches(itemDescription.ToLower(), @"\w+")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Value)
    );
descrWords.UnionWith(wordSet);
if (descrWords.Count > 0) {
    // Your description contains at least one of the words
}
```

---

You can do the comparison in many different ways. E.g. by using LINQ

```
if (words.Union(
    Regex.Matches(itemDescription.ToLower(), @"\w+")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Value)
    ).Any())
{
    ...
}
```

---

Note: It is not enough to look if a string contains a word with

```
s.Contains("great")
```

since it would find parts of words like "greatness" as well.

---

If you need to find phrases as well, the approach described above does not work. You will need to combine a Regex search with a loop or a LINQ statement. Let's use a regex expression of the type

```
\bWordOrPhrase\b
```

`\b` matches word boundaries. In order to be sure not to introduce some special regex character into the regex expression we need to escape our word or phrase.

```
bool found = Regex.IsMatch(description, @"\b" + Regex.Escape(wordOrPhrase) + @"\b");
```

Finally we must do this test for all the word and phrases in the list. Let's put everything together:

```
string dir = @"C:\MyDataPath";
string filename = comboTemplates.SelectedItem.ToString();
string filepath = Path.Combine(dir, filename);

string[] words = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);
```

Then test your descriptions

```
string itemDescription = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("description")[0].InnerText;
if (words.Any(
    wordOrPhrase =>
    Regex.IsMatch(itemDescription,
                  @"\b" + Regex.Escape(wordOrPhrase) + @"\b",
                  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sir, thank you. But may I know how do I write the `if` statement like this `if (itemDescription.ToLower().Contains(wordSet))` ? I am not too sure how to write that as it will return error. How do I express "if the child nodes contain the words/phrases in the array"? Thanks.

Comment: I am a little lost. May I know what should I do within the `if (descrWords.Count > 0) { }`?

Comment: The difficulty is that you have two sets of words (or phrases). The words from the file and the words from the description. It is easy to see whether a word is contained in a string; however, it is not as easy to test if any word contained in a list is contained in a text. I hope that the second solution I sketched out will solve your problem.

Comment: I do not really know should I put this line `bool found = Regex.IsMatch(description, @"\b" + Regex.Escape(wordOrPhrase) + @"\b");` at?

Comment: `string.Contains(x)` does only look if string `x` is contained in another one. It does not work with a whole list.

Comment: Sorry for the `if (descrWords.Count > 0) { }`. It was the remaining of another idea that I revised. I deleted it now.

Comment: You don't need the line `bool found = Regex.IsMatch(...`. I only used it in order to introduce the regex part. Later, I embed it directly into a LINQ query. (I did not want to explain all at once).

Comment: Thank you Olivier. :) It works by using the last two parts of your codes and currently I am testing it out to see if it works in every way that I want it to be. :) I appreciate your detailed explanation! I learnt new things!